# Vue js pass a function from child chile to another child component on a click event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to pass a function when a button is clicked, the button is clicked in a child element, then passed through a parent element to another child component, and i dont want to use the store for that, How can i do that?

components/footer/footer.vue
-- This is where the button is clicked

```html
<template>
    <div class="footer-bottom-header-menu-bar mob"  @click="showMenu">
        <img src="~/assets/svg/menubar.svg" alt="+" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        showMenu() {
            this.$emit("show-menu");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

layouts/default.vue
--This is the parent component where that receives the click function  and is to pass it into the `app-header`

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header />
        <Nuxt />
        <app-footer @show-menu="showMenu()"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import header from "~/components/header/header";
import footer from "~/components/footer/footer";

export default {
    components: {
        'app-header': header,
        'app-footer': footer
    },
    methods: {
        showMenu() {
            console.log("clicked");
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

components/header/header.vue
-- I want the click function to perform an action inside this component

```html
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            showMenuBar: false
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: ... pass it via the event bus?

Comment: @vector pretty much the same as `store` tbh.

Comment: If you don't want to use a store for that, you need to do it the other way: `emit` + `listener`, and trigger some methods. PS: passing a function down or up is an anti-pattern in Vue (it is common in React tho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare any attribut on your parent component:

```
data() {
    return { toBeWatched: 0 };
}
```

- Then pass it like a [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) from the parent to the header child:
  `<app-header :Trigger="toBeWatched" />`
- When you listen to the `@show-menu` [event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) (comming from footer child),
  make any change on your attribut:
  `<app-footer @show-menu="toBeWatched++" />`
- Finally you can [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) for this change on your header child and
  trigger your function.

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showMenuBar: false
      };
    },
    props: ['Trigger'],
    watch: {
      Trigger() {
        this.showMenuBar = !this.showMenuBar; // or do whatever you want
        console.log('showMenuBar : ' + this.showMenuBar);
      }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Why are you worried about passing a function around?

When you `emit` the `show-menu` event simply toggle a piece of data in your parent component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header :showMenuBar="showMenuBar" />
        <Nuxt />
        <app-footer @show-menu="showMenu"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import header from "~/components/header/header";
import footer from "~/components/footer/footer";

export default {
    components: {
        'app-header': header,
        'app-footer': footer
    },
    data() {
      return {
        showMenuBar: false;
      };
    },
    methods: {
        showMenu() {
            // I would make this more dynamic than always
            // hardcoding it to true, but you get the idea
            this.showMenuBar = true;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Then in your `AppHeader` simply take it in as a prop:

```html
<script>
export default {
    props: {
      showMenuBar: { 
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false,
    },
}
</script>
```